# How to Install Driver for Camera and Touchscreen in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: drivers

I have Windows Tablet Thunderbook (w802) and I want to have Ubuntu on it. It is really important that Camera and Touchscreen are working properly.
Camera is OmniVision ov2680 and the Touchscreen is Goodix gt9110p.

I found online goodix.c and something similar for OmniVision, but I don’t know what to do with these files.

I already installed Ubuntu 22.10 and Camera and Touchscreen are not working. In Windows 10 witch is also installed, both are working properly.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you

---

xinput

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                   id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer         id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:14                id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:14       id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]    
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:14       id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                  id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard        id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:14               id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput - on Xorg

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Consumer Control     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Consumer Control     id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Mouse        id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ sof-bytcht nau8824 Headset                id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ gpio-keys                                 id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ gpio-keys                                 id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Cherry USB keyboard                       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Consumer Control     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Cherry USB keyboard System Control        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 System Control       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Consumer Control     id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Cherry USB keyboard Consumer Control      id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Did you already install Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. Windows 10 is also installed.

Comment: So do camera and touchscreen work?

Comment: They are not working. That is why I need help. To get them working properly.

Comment: Please add this to your question. You can [edit].

Comment: Please add  output of `xinput` to your question.

Comment: Did you try to switch to xorg?

Comment: @Pilot6 No I didn't

Comment: Try to boot to xorg from the login screen.

Comment: Ubuntu on Xorg didn't help.

Comment: Please add output of `xinput` on Xorg.